# How many times must I toss a coin in order that the odds are more than 100 to 1 that I get at least one head?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

How many times must I toss a coin in order that the odds are more than 100 to 1 that I get at least one head?
I believe that it is 10 times as if the coin is flipped ten times there is only ten outcomes that include only 1 head out of 1024 total outcomes. Is this correct?

Comment: The problem asks about the odds of at least one head. For ten coin flips, there is only one possibility that does not have at least one head, so the odds in this case are closer to 1000 to 1 than to 100 to 1.

Comment: Perhaps you want to beat $\color\red{1000}:1$ ? In this case, $n=10$ would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chance of getting at least one head is $1 - (\frac{1}{2})^n$

This equation has to equal $99 \%$, which gives us the following:

$$1 - \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^n = 0.99$$
$$\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^n = 0.01$$
$$n \log\frac{1}{2} = \log0.01$$
$$n = \frac{\log0.01}{\log\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$n = 6.6438...$$

Obviously we can't have $6.6438...$ number of tries, which means it must go up to the nearest integer, which means we must have $7$ tries to have more than $99 \%$ to get at least one head.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. You want to compare getting at least one head to getting no heads at all; the probability of getting no heads at all during $k$ tosses is the same as getting all tails, i.e. $(1/2)^k$. The probability of getting at least one head is simply the complement of this, i.e. $1-(1/2)^k$. Thus you want $1-(1/2)^k$ to be at least 100 times greater than $(1/2)^k$. Thus we want 
$$
\frac{1-(1/2)^k}{(1/2)^k}=2^k-1>100;
$$
can you go from here?

Comment: Yes,Will do thanks

Answer (score 1):

If we toss $n$ times, the probability to get at least one head is $$1-(\frac{1}{2})^n$$ For $n=7$, we have a probability of $0.992\cdots$ , which is larger than $0.99$ hence the answer is $7$. To be exact, the probability of a failure is $\frac{1}{128}$, for $n=6$, the failure-probability would be $\frac{1}{64}$, which is still larger than $\frac{1}{100}$